# get row number in order by using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am using mysql and I am trying to get the row number of ther ordered list I get back. But the @rownum := @rownum + 1 will return null using a native query.

Is there another way to solve it either by using JPA syntax or altering the MySQL query.

Query updated with info from comment. However making this object a "Hallmaster" object will not set the position field in Hallmaster. If I make it a generic List it will contain the correct information.

```
listHallmastaren = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT  id, @position:=@position+1 AS position, " +
    " e.name, e.score FROM HALLMASTER e, (SELECT @position:=0) t ORDER BY e.score desc", Hallmaster.class).getResultList();
```

Added Hallmaster class

```
public class Hallmaster implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id; // still set automatically

    @Transient
    private Long position;
    private String name;
    private Integer score;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Hallmaster() {
        super();

        this.position = 0L;
        this.name = "Nytt";
        this.score = 0;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void setPosition(long position) {
        this.position = position;
    }   
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public Integer getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try modyfying your query a bit: `SELECT  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position, e.name, e.score FROM HALLMASTER e, (SELECT@rownum:=0)t ORDER BY e.score desc`

Comment: Glad you managed to pull it through :)